# OpenLayers, get picture of drawn area on map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I would like to be able to grab a picture of the drawn area on the map. something like this:
When this is the entire shown map:
[entire map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW1A3.jpg)
i would like to get an image of this area:
[selected map area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OGUD.png)

The zoom level doesn't matter

i cant find any docs about it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can try this [ol-map-screenshot](https://github.com/jmmluna/ol-map-screenshot)